# How can I save integer by using %*c in scanf?

Tags: c

```
scanf("%c%d%*c%d", &RC1, &base1, &column1);
printf("%d", column1);
```

This is part of my code, and I'm trying to save data as integer in variable `column1` using `scanf`.
But when I print the value of it, it shows the address of variable allocated in memory.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's the type of `RC1` and what is your input?

Comment: Using `scanf` to read characters and integers at the same time can be problematic.

Comment: Are you always discarding everything after the "and"?

Comment: RC1 is character .base1 and column1 are integer . inputs are in C2_1 form  which C can be any other character.

Comment: Try making this a [mcve], please!

Comment: You should show at least one line of input data, and the output you get from that data, and you should check that `scanf()` returned 3 before using any of the variables.  Please (re)read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — you've got the minimal part down, but you've gone too far so the code is not complete.  The input, actual and expected output are also crucial information.  Given a line of input such as `X23-19`, you should be able to demonstrate that `RC1` holds `'X'`, `base1` holds `23`, and `column1` holds `19`.